# Javascript oop-like fail(?!?)

Tags: javascript, oop, function

Consider this:

```
function f2(x) {
    return x+1;
};

X = function(){
    this.f1=function (x) {
      return 2*f2(x);
    }

    return this;
};
```

then `x = new X(); x.f1(1)` works fine.

But when i want to do this:

```
X = function(){
    this.f2 = function(x) {
        return x+1;
    };

    this.f1=function (x) {
        return 2*f2(x);
    }

    return this;
};
```

The same statement will complain that it can't find f2.
In, for example c#, you can say

```
class X {
   int f2(int x){return x+1;}
   int f1(int x){return 2*f2(x);}
}
```

and this will work

```
X x=new X();
x.f1(1)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference `f2` in your second code block, you'll need to use `this.f2`. `this` references the context in which the function is being executed. Since you call `f1` in the following way:

```
x.f1();
```

... the `context` is set to the instance, `x`.

JavaScript does not make instance variables available to the scope in the same way as scope variables, i.e. those directly available:

```
X = function(){

    var f2 = 123;

    this.f2 = function(x) {
        return x+1;
    };

    this.f1=function (x) {

        console.log(f2); // => 123
        console.log(this.f2); // => function(){}

        return 2 * this.f2(x);
    };

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

because you forgot **this**.f2. Javascript don't see class variables without this

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the f2 with the this keyword explicitly.

```
X = function(){
    this.f2 = function(x) {
        return x+1;
    };

    this.f1=function (x) {
        return 2*this.f2(x);
    }

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have the implicit `this` that you get in C#.  You need to add the this in:

```
X = function(){
    this.f2 = function(x) {
        return x+1;
    };

    this.f1=function (x) {
        return 2*this.f2(x);
    };

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X = function(){
       this.f2 = function(x) {
            return x+1;
       };    
       this.f1=function (x) {
            return 2*this.f2(x);  // <-- Need this here since it is not implicit
       }
       return this;
    };
```